# Javascript copy paste strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, clipboard

**I have the following HTML and Javascript:**

```js
function copyToClipboard(element_id){
    var aux = document.createElement("div");
    aux.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
    aux.innerHTML = document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML;
    aux.setAttribute("onfocus", "document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)");
    document.body.appendChild(aux);
    aux.focus();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
```

```html
<h1>Society description format</h1>
<div id="society-description">
    <div>
        <h2><strong>Introduction</strong></h2>
        <p>E.g. Welcome to Trent TV!</p>
        <h2><strong>A brief description of your society</strong></h2>
        <p>E.g. Trent TV is the official, award-winning TV Station of Nottingham Trent Students’ Union.</p>
        <h2><strong>Your aims and objectives</strong></h2>
        <p>E.g. We produce content that covers a variety of genres, from festival coverage and music videos to panel
            shows, sports highlights and news features.</p>
        <h2><strong>What you can expect to get involved in</strong></h2>
        <p>E.g - Society socials, networking events, workshops, guest speakers etc.</p>
        <h2><strong>How to get involved</strong></h2>
        <p>E.g. Everyone and anyone who has a passion for television is welcome to join, regardless of their experience,
            and will play a vital part in the success in our station, whether it's being a runner, camera operator,
            presenter, producer or just someone who is full of ideas.</p>
        <h2><strong>Social media / Contact</strong></h2>
        <p>
            <img alt="Email" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nusdigital/image/images/177590/original/SOCIAL-MEDIA-ICONS-EMAIL-BLACK-300.png"
                style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" title="Email" />&nbsp;
            <img alt="Facebook" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nusdigital/image/images/177570/original/SOCIAL-MEDIA-ICONS-FACEBOOK-BLACK-300.png"
                style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" title="Facebook" />&nbsp;
            <img alt="Twitter" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nusdigital/image/images/177571/original/SOCIAL-MEDIA-ICONS-TWITTER-BLACK-300.png"
                style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" title="Twitter" />&nbsp;
            <img alt="Instagram" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nusdigital/image/images/177573/original/SOCIAL-MEDIA-ICONS-INSTAGRAM-BLACK-300.png"
                style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" title="Instagram" />&nbsp;
            <img alt="Snapchat" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nusdigital/image/images/177572/original/SOCIAL-MEDIA-ICONS-SNAPCHAT-BLACK-300.png"
                style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" title="Snapchat" />&nbsp;
            <img alt="Web" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nusdigital/image/images/204535/original/SOCIAL-MEDIA-ICONS-WEB-BLACK-300.png"
                style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" title="Web" />&nbsp;
            <img alt="YouTube" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nusdigital/image/images/204534/original/SOCIAL-MEDIA-ICONS-YOUTUBE-BLACK-300.png"
                style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" title="YouTube" />&nbsp;
            <img alt="WhatsApp" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nusdigital/image/images/231639/original/SOCIAL-MEDIA-ICONS-WHATSAPP-50PX-PADDING.png"
                style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" title="WhatsApp" />&nbsp;
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="target">&nbsp;</div>
<p><a class="btn-2018" href="javascript:" onclick="copyToClipboard('society-description')">Copy to clipboard</a></p>
```

To copy the text WITH formatting. 
testing using https://html-online.com/editor/

**It works perfectly except the last image ignores the width and height attributes.
The div within div above fixed the second to last image which exhibited the same behavior.

Is this a unfixable bug?**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. So when you paste the copied html content somewhere, the images display in another size than the `60px` by `60px` which are defined in the `style` attributes? If that's the case it probably depends on the software where the content gets pasted into. I've just tested this code and pasted the content in a Google Docs file and images display the same as in the original html.

Comment: Not quite all the images except the last one display as 60x60. Tested in html editor and mk editor.